# jQuery Autocompletar en CodeIgniter, sin poder resolver

Tags: php, codeigniter

Buenas **Si me autocompleta**, pero quiero que se guarde el valor del código, `id` y `descripcion` en los campos correspondientes,veo que console.log muestra `{label: "3321", value: "3321"}`, lo cual esos valores es el codigo q seleccione, como seria para que me muestre `codigo,id,descripcion` en los `input`, Gracias.

Aclaro que es la única forma que me funciona el autocompletar, ya intente varias.

Controlador:

```
  public function getarticulos() {
    $q = trim($this->input->get('term')); 
     $result = array();
    $productoresult = $this->articulo_model->find($q);       
    foreach ($productoresult as $i =>$articulo) {
        $result[$i]['id'] = $articulo->id;
        $result[$i]['codigo'] = $articulo->codigo;
        $result[$i]['descripcion'] = $articulo->descripcion;
        $result[$i]['precioactual'] = $articulo->precioactual;


    }          
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Vista:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {              
 $(function() {
    var cache = {};
    $( "#txtcodigo" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 2,
      source: function( request, response ) {
        var menus = new Array();
        var term = request.term;
        if ( term in cache ) {
          response( cache[ term ] );
          return;
        }

        $.getJSON( "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/articulo/getarticulos", request, function( result) {
//              cache[ term ] = result;  

        var count = result.length;
//        console.log(result);
//                console.log(count);
                  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    menus[i] = { codigo: result[i].codigo, id: result[i].id, descripcion:result[i].descripcion};

                    menus[i] = result[i].codigo;


                }
          response(menus);

        });


      },
       select: function( event, ui ) {   
           console.log(ui.item);
          $("#txtcodigo").val(ui.item.codigo);//si escribo ui.item.value si   
          $("#txtid").val(ui.item.id);        //guarda el valor del codigo  
          $("#txtdescripcion").val(ui.item.descripcion);  
                    return false;

             }         

    });
  });


     });
</script>

  </head>

  <label for="txtcodigo">Codigo: </label>
  <input id="txtcodigo" value="">
    <label for="txtid">id: </label> 
    <input id="txtid" value="">
  <label for="txtdescripcion">Descripcion: </label> 
    <input id="txtdescripcion" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

A tus etiquetas input les falta el tipo

```
<input type="text" name="fname">
```

Puedes aplicar la etiqueta "delay" para disminuir la cantidad de peticiones. Ya que un cambio en el texto es una nueva consulta a la base de datos.

```
$( "#txtcodigo" ).autocomplete({
   /* ... */
   delay: 500
});
```

Cambien deberías validar lo que se envía al servidor, en esta linea le pasas directo a la base de datos lo que envía el cliente:

```
$productoresult = $this->articulo_model->find($q);
```

usando codeingniter aquí explica como hacerlo https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

respondiendo a tu pregunta te doy este enlace

http://www.smarttutorials.net/jquery-autocomplete-multiple-fields-using-ajax-php-mysql-example/

creo que es justo lo que quieres hacer, aunque no usa codeigniter, será fácil adaptarlo teniendo la idea.